# how can i retrieve every row in a dataframe with a definite column name and write "Hi 5 " without using a for loop?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, data-mining, data-analysis

I have a big data set with more than 60000 records and i want to write every record to excel without using for loop.
For example:

i have df as

```
name id 
ss    1
ed    45
dd    34
...
...
eff   45
```

upto 60000 records , i want to retrieve all those records and save to excel as

```
Hi1
Hi45
hi34
```

in excel i need this to save as one column

Comment: Small case or larger case `H`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: df = pd.read_csv("a.csv")

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
  name  id
0   ss    1
1   ed   45
2   dd   34

In [7]: df.name = "Hi"

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  name  id
0   Hi    1
1   Hi   45
2   Hi   34

In [9]: df.to_excel("data.xlsx")
```